Problem with passing ImageSource in Release MAUI
When debugging, everything is transferred correctly and the method for deleting images works fine, but in the release version I encountered a problem that ImageSource is not transferred, what could this be related to?
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedImageList}"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame
                    Padding="-1"
                    Margin="10,5,0,0"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image
                            Source="{Binding .}"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            WidthRequest="50" InputTransparent="True"
                            />
                        <Image Source="cross.svg" Aspect="Fill" WidthRequest="17" HeightRequest="17" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="2" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ChatWIndowViewModel}}, Path=RemoveImageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>

public void RemoveImage(ImageSource image)
{
    SelectedImageList.Remove(image);
    if (SelectedImageList.Count == 0)
    {
        if (!EditMode)
        {
            IsImageSelected = false;
            IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            EditImage = false;
        }
    }
}

I tried to call commands in different ways, made a call through a button and through a tapped button, but nothing helped

Assuming SelectedImageList is a list of ImageSource, then specify x:Datatype for CollectionView's DataTemplate as below
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="ImageSource">

And also in command, It's better to assume the parameter as object and then check whether it's an ImageSource.
   public void RemoveImage(object obj)
   {
      if(obj is ImageSource image)
      SelectedImageList.Remove(image);
      ....
   }

